# Angular $rootScope.$broadcast() event caught twice in controller

Tags: angularjs, rootscope

Broadcating event on button click :-

```
$scope.onButtonClick = function(){
    $rootScope.$broadcast('onButtonClick');
}
```

And catching event in another controller :-

```
$rootScope.$on('onButtonClick',function(event){
  alert("catched");
  console.log(event);
});
```

But it caught twice even though it fired only once. Why is that?

Comment: Most probably two instances of the controller are active. One common reason is use of `$routeProvider` controller and `ng-controller` on the same view.

Comment: so how to resolve it? can you please help me?

Comment: Do you have your controller instantiated in view with ng-controller as Chandermani suggested? If so, remove the ng-controller attribute. Instantiating the controller with ng-controller,  uirouter and ngRouter is a one OR the other choice. If you instantiate the controller twice you will have two instances of it.

Comment: @Chandermani : thank you :) its working. I am giving controller in uirouting only and it works :)

Comment: Let me add it as answer so that the question marked answered and I can take some credit :)

Answer (score 44, accepted):

As it turned out the multiple controllers were instantiated due to `ng-controller` declaration in html and also as part of state setup for `ui-router`.

The solution is to remove one of the declarations.

Comment: removed ng-controller declaration in html as I have already added it as state setup in router. Things works fine now. Thank you!

Answer (score 10):

If you broadcast an event on `$rootScope`, you can catch the event on each controller `$scope`.
IMO you should not catch the event on the `$rootScope`.

```
$scope.$on('onButtonClick',function(event){
  alert("catched");
  console.log(event);
});
```

I've created a plunker showcase, which shows that it works exactly as expected. [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/kpOYIhZqdVxYRERfoehB?p=preview)

It could be possible that you have multiple instances of the same controller, where you catch the event. Please check this as  Chandermani suggested.

Comment: @user59442: Your first statement is valid and good for a comment. But your last statement is wrong. This is not an answer.

Comment: this helped me for some reason

Comment: What does the opinion have to do with the real behavior, those are matters of facts and you should provide an answer based on some kind of concrete factual knowledge, not based on a personal opinion.

Answer (score 4):

Angular `$rootScope.$broadcast()` event caught twice in controller

```
$scope.$on('saveCancelLeadInfo', function (event, args) {
    if ($scope.$$listenerCount["saveCancelLeadInfo"] > 1) {
        $scope.$$listenerCount["saveCancelLeadInfo"] = 0;
    }
    your code here
});
```

Comment: this helped me.