# download-item.cancel() emit 'done' twice?

Tags: node.js, electron

- Electron version: 1.4.0
- Operating system: MacOS(Darwin Kernel Version 15.4.0)

#### Expected behavior

When I trigger downloadItem.cancel()，event 'done' trigger once that state is 'cancel'

#### Actual behavior

event 'done' trigger twice. It's a bug or trigger twice purposely?

Why?

#### Reproduce

```
git clone https://github.com/dengyaolong/electron-download-item-cancel-fired-twice
npm i
npm start
```

Save , see the logs. cancel fired twice

Answer (score 0):

First of all, if you can update electron you should :) 
The issue you describe remembers me at broadcasts fired twice because the controller was initialized multiple times, try this solution:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/25805540/970470

cheers

Comment: maybe I need to read the source code to  solve the problem .thanks~